# list assignment index out of range. Can you help me ?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
j=1
n=int(input())
flag=[]*29
a=[]*29
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=1.0/(i+2)
for j in range(2**29):
    temp=j
    index=0
    sum=0
    while temp>0 and index<29:
        flag[index]=temp%2
        index=index+1
        sum+=(temp%2)*a[index]
        temp=temp/2
if sum==1:
    count=0
    index=index+1
    for i in range(index):
        if flag[i]==1:
            count+=1
    if count==n:
        for i in range(len(flag)):
            if flag[i]!=0:
                print(flag[i]+"/"+(i+2)+"")
```

---

log：IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I can not fix.list assignment index out of range. Can you help me ?

Comment: What are you expecting `[]*29` to do?

Answer (score 0):

"index=index+1" would set that to 30 which is out of range when calling flag[i] when i = max(index)

Comment: Thank you! How can I modify？

Comment: Removing the line should work I think - need more context to understand what you're trying to do though to answer further